# Does enabling java let my ISP find out what I am doing?

Tags: security, javascript

As the title says: if I enable javascript can my ISP know what I am doing? As in do I become transparent (somehow) to my ISP? I am only interested to know the ISP side, as the tor FAQ (&co) are quite clear on the visited address side.

To give a quick example, suppose I am at a concert, in a crowd, somewhere. If I talk to a person I don't want others to know that I talk to that person or what. Of course, this is *only* for the case I am enabling javascript. If this happens, I accept that the other person knows.

---

My apologies, I should have mentioned this is directly (strictly) related to the tor borwser. I thought being in the tor SE would make this redundant,  parently I was wrong.

Comment: Use Tails then. If you want to use former Gmail safe way with Javascript.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question talks about using JavaScript, but I don't see any point where Tor is involved. Your question might be a better fit for https://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: @less clueless citizen tails is a live OS, I don't have there all my programs, settings, etc. I want to use TBB for daily browsing and, if I'm using it, it's because I'm mainly interested in being complete opaque towards my ISP. If I choose to be less so towards the internet, that'd be my choice.

Answer (score 1):

Java is not JavaScript.

- [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29)
- [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)

JavaScript can be probably dangerous because it can interfere (?) with your computer way more than the regular browsing without it. So servers could gain more information about you.

Ask yourself: How could ISP do that?

Servers will know more. You are connected to the internet thanks to your ISP.

Comment: A good point. But now does this mean gmail or similar sites are out of the question if I want my privacy? Currently there are 2 installed copies (from archives), one with and the other without java/javascript ("ultimate anonimity"), but with the latter I can't do too many things for daily browsing -- which is what I want to use tor for. So I habe to use the former for gmail&co. Are there solutions for this?

Comment: I know I said it's a good point, but I presume the answer came before I specified it's related to tor; I still don't know if (and how) my ISP can find out about me since the chain is me>ISP>tor1>..., so even if I connect to the net through my ISP, they only see me and the 1st tor connection, encrypted. So, still, how can enabling java/javascript be compromising my privacy anywhere else than on the 3rd tor connection and net, tor3<>net?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript won't make difference in network terms, however, it will make your computer more vulnerable to attacks. Chatting through Tor is not really a good option, because the exit node can monitor into your traffic, so the best bet would be always use HTTPS and also use GPG

Comment: No chatting, just browsing. Gmail is one example, and it uses https. So then, to clarify, my ISP can't know what I'm doing with java enabled?